# Flutter android bug on using tensorflow package tflite_flutter

Tags: android, flutter, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, tflite

I'm trying to use tensorflow lite packages from new flutter project connecting my samsung phone. I have only modified in **android/app/build.gradle** file

```
compileSdkVersion 31 

minSdkVersion 21
        
targetSdkVersion 31
```

and in **pubspec.yaml**

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  camera: ^0.9.4+5
  image: ^3.1.0
  tflite_flutter: ^0.9.0
  tflite_flutter_helper: ^0.3.1
  path_provider: ^2.0.8
```

However, I get following errors. Anyone can help me resolving thos errors? what should I do?

```
Launching lib/main.dart on SM N981N in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
e: /Users/sangyoonhan/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/tflite_flutter_helper-0.3.1/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tfliteflutter/tflite_flutter_helper/TfliteFlutterHelperPlugin.kt: (43, 1): Class 'TfliteFlutterHelperPlugin' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun onRequestPermissionsResult(p0: Int, p1: Array<(out) String!>, p2: IntArray): Boolean defined in io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.RequestPermissionsResultListener
e: /Users/sangyoonhan/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/tflite_flutter_helper-0.3.1/android/src/main/kotlin/com/tfliteflutter/tflite_flutter_helper/TfliteFlutterHelperPlugin.kt: (143, 2): 'onRequestPermissionsResult' overrides nothing

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':tflite_flutter_helper:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
```

I will leave flutter doctor information. I got no clue why these errors are occuring

```
(base) sangyoonhan@Sangyoonui-MacBookPro untitled % flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.8, on macOS 13.0.1 22A400 darwin-x64, locale ko-KR)
    • Flutter version 3.3.8 on channel stable at /Users/sangyoonhan/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 52b3dc25f6 (8주 전), 2022-11-09 12:09:26 +0800
    • Engine revision 857bd6b74c
    • Dart version 2.18.4
    • DevTools version 2.15.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/sangyoonhan/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14C18
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.74.1)
    • VS Code at /Users/sangyoonhan/Downloads/학교/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension can be installed from:
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[✓] Connected device (4 available)
    • SM N981N (mobile)          • R3CR10GC91P                          • android-arm64  • Android 12 (API 31)
    • iPhone 14 Pro Max (mobile) • 6D97D66D-63AB-4822-9EF5-D0C7DA86B6D4 • ios            •
      com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-2 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)            • macos                                • darwin-x64     • macOS 13.0.1 22A400
      darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)               • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 108.0.5359.124

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Somebody help me!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem when I connected the camera package.
This link is a solution to the problem to remove the error related to ':tflite_flutter_helper:compileDebugKotlin'.

https://github.com/am15h/tflite_flutter_helper/issues/57#issuecomment-1128960033

After fixing this error, the error will appear due to a conflict of using the camera package, because the tflite_flutter_helper: ^0.3.1 package uses an older version of the camera than the one used in your project.

To solve your problem, try:

1. replace:

   tflite_flutter_helper: ^0.3.1

to

```
tflite_flutter_helper:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/filofan1/tflite_flutter_helper.git
      ref: 783f15e5a87126159147d8ea30b98eea9207ac70
```

2. Move the camera package from dependencies to dependency_overrides
3. *flutter pub get* or *flutter clean* and *flutter pub get*

An example of how you should get it in your pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
 
  image: ^3.1.0
  tflite_flutter: ^0.9.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.8
  tflite_flutter_helper:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/filofan1/tflite_flutter_helper.git
      ref: 783f15e5a87126159147d8ea30b98eea9207ac70
 
dependency_overrides:
  camera: 0.9.4+5
```